# Postgres using a JSONB column instead of defined columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres has a lot of support for JSON (even indexing). I want to just put 1 jsonb field called `everything` instead of defining of bunch of typed columns (mongodb style).

But I assume this is a bad idea. My question is: **Why shouldn't I do this?** Is the only con just the fact that it'll probably take extra storage space?

(My table has a lot of optional fields which is why I want to do this)

Comment: That will depend on how well you want your data structured. A json field will make you lose normalization (and that is debatable) but for an application that it have a defined object (like a simple pojo) it could be a good option. I'm an old school I always prefer to have a good and well defined and normalized database model. Nowadays people tend to use json data. Anyways if you are using a json data just to get rid of columns i disagree but if it is to represent an object it is fine.

Comment: first concern - FK. jsonb indexing is great, but having constraints would be difficult

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons:

- If the JSON blob has foreign keys to other columns, I don't think you can add a `REFERENCES` constraint.
- With columns you can enforce `NOT NULL` constraints very easily, but with JSON you'll have to write `CHECK` constraints for each required value.
- JSON has fewer types than Postgres. For instance, no date/time/timestamp, no intervals, no ranges, just one kind of numeric type, no IP addresses, no binary data.
- Over time if you add/move/delete fields in the JSON structure, you'll find that older rows become obsolete and have JSON your app doesn't understand. Using regular columns forces you to keep the whole table up-to-date.